# How to add a complete date on the x-axis of the kendo scatterline series type

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo chart, scatter line series type, example:[like this](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/error-bars)

I can able to plot the values on the kendo chart.[see the output](https://ibb.co/D5sWK3z)

I have an array `series_array`, It is dynamic, contains objects like this

```
{ 
   name:"series1", 
   data:[x:"11/12/2018",y:"20",low:"5",high:"10"]
}
```

jquery code to fill kendo chart is : 
code:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
title:{ text:"my error chart"},
seriesDefaults:{
         type:"scatterLine",
         yErrorLowField:"low",
         yErrorHighField:"high",
         xField:"x",
         yField:"y"
},
series:seris_array
});
```

Problem is how to get x-axis or categorial axis values like "11/12/2018"(Full Date).

Comment: Can you explain further what the result you want looks like, or better yet, add an image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  Right now in the output image [link](https://ibb.co/D5sWK3z) x axis is like this > Nov'14   Dec'14  Jan'15  but I want output  like this > 11/11/2014     15/12/2014    24/01/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[xAxis.labels.format](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/xaxis.labels#xAxis.labels.format)**:

```
   xAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "{0:d}"
    },
   },
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/ZVbOOx)**